# Visual Studio 2013 Update 5: Unable to create unattend installation

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, unattend-file

I'm trying to create the `AdminDeployment.xml` file for Visual Studio 2013 Professional Update 5 installation in unattended mode. I did not find information about VS 2013, as for 2015 it could be done with `/CreateAdminFile` command line key ([see documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/how-to-create-and-run-an-unattended-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2015)), also I clearly remember, I did it with Visual Studio 2012, so the key definitely should be implememted

When I'm trying to run `vs_professional.exe` with `/CreateAdminFile`, this way:

```
vs_professional.exe /CreateAdminFile C:\Users\<Username>\Downloads
```

or this way:

```
vs_professional.exe /CreateAdminFile C:\Users\<Username>\Downloads\AdminDeployment.xml
```

it displays command-line help, and there's no `/CreateAdminFile` key among options. Interestingly, just `/AdminFile` is there, so my problem is to create file, my VS 2013 probably knows how to handle it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appeared in Visual Studio 2013 you don't need to generate `AdminDeployment.xml` file, it already has a template, saved in a root directory on installation media. You just need to change the value of the NoWeb attribute of the BundleCustomizations element from "default" to "yes"

```
<BundleCustomizations TargetDir="default" NoWeb="yes"/>
```

and edit selectable items for components you want to install

```
<SelectableItemCustomization Id="VC_MFC_Libraries" Hidden="no" Selected="yes" />
```

After that you need to run installation with the key `/AdminFile` to set the location of unattend file

```
vs_professional.exe /AdminFile C:\Users\<Username>\Downloads
```